# 401 Unauthorized when calling web service in provider hosted app

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, authentication, provider-hosted-app

I have build a SharePoint provider hosted app (high trust) that has a WCF service that also calls a custom webservice that is hosted in SharePoint.

The app WCF service is called from a SharePoint workflow.

But when it reaches the call to the custom SharePoint web service, we get a 401 Unauthorized.

Does anybody have any ideas how I can solve this.

Comment: Can you tell us what authentication method you're using?  If it is SAML/ADFS are you using a custom claim provider?

Comment: Because we could not find any solution for it at that moment, we created some server side code in the workflow. It was a high trust app, so it works with certificates and as authentication we used windows auth.